# Filter SQL Query By removing some character

Tags: sql

Filter SQL Query By removing some character

Is it possible to filter sql query result by removing some character. For example :

If output of any query is "123$456"
Is it any how I can filter in query itself to return "123456" and remove the "$" character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `replace()` in most versions of SQL:

```
select replace(col, '$', '')
from <whatever>;
```

Comment: To add on it, how to carry out this. Result --> 123$456&8
I want $to be replaced by $$ and & by && so result becomes---> 123$$456&&8
??

Answer (score 0):

```
Select replace(column,'$','')  from table
```